# How to change a search direction in terminal

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I'm under OS X El Capitan 10.11.1.
When I try to search in terminal text by `command + F` it starts to search from the text above rather than from bottom as it was in terminal on Ubuntu.
So how can I change a direction of search to start a search from a bottom of text history in terminal?
Thanks any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down the shift key. Then press the return button to do the search. It will search backwards. Assuming you are starting a new search it will start at the top but go backwards so it will loop to the bottom with the first return press. Just keep holding shift while pressing return to keep going backwards up the history.